# OpenMP reduction clause

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, openmp

I have a loop which I am trying to parallelize with OpenMP. The construct I have in code is this,

```
for(int x = 0; x < <condition>; x++) 
{
    aggregate += <return value from very costly function(param1)>;
}
```

I am trying to parallelize it as follows,

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int x = 0; x < <condition>; x++) 
{
    #pragma omp parallel private(param1)
    aggregate += <return value from very costly function(param1)>;
}
```

It crashes if I dont make param1 private since all threads use the same memory. But also I always get aggregate's value as 0. I understand that this is because I have not reduced it to sum each thread's local calculated value of aggregate. I am confused at this, how do I do that to sum all the values from the threads?

This is in Visual Studio 13 C++.

Comment: `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:aggregate)`

Comment: Tried that, doesnt still help, the parameter is private and is a class object with multiple pointers and class objetcs inside it, i doubt if that is being carried over properly to the threads..

Comment: Just post a minimal complete and verifiable example.

Comment: Microsoft's OpenMP implementation only supports a very old dialect of OpenMP. Use a modern OpenMP compiler (intel, GCC, LLVM) that allows user defined reductions (and ensure that whatever type "aggregate" is has appropriate constructors...)